# Running Dependent Queries with SparkSQL using Spark Session

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0, spark-hive

We have 3 queries which are currently running on HIVE.

**Using Spark 2.1.0**

We are trying to Run that using Spark SQL but by using the SparkSession(like wrapping with Scala code making a Jar & then Submit using Spark-Submit)

Now for Example lets say :
Query-1 uses 3 tables (Table - a, b & c) and Insert into table --> **Output_Table_1**

Query-2 uses few other tables(performing Joins) and **output_table_1** which is populated from the output of Query-1. This gives **output_table_2**

Similarly Query-3 uses few tables & may or may not use **output_table_1** and/or **output_table_2**(we are not sure on this as still designing)

Currently the way i am doing this is writing all the queries in a property file and reading it in `def main` using `Typesafe.ConfigFactory` (Please suggest if there is any better way)

In the `def main(){}` what i am doing is :

```
val query_1 = spark.sql('query1')
query_1.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("output_table_1")
```

Now when i am doing the Below step It throws an Error - output_table_1 not found

```
val query_2 = spark.sql('query2')
query_2.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("output_table_2")
```

Similarly for the 3rd Query and table i am getting Same error. So basically i am trying to Chain the Queries & use the output of Initial queries in the later ones. I cannot break the queries into smaller Dataframes as they are complex.

How to go ahead with such scenario. Also let me know what is the Best Practice to achieve this ?

Comment: Any Help here ???

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do

```
query_1.registerTempTable("output_table_1")
```

Comment: And Then how will i use it in query_2 ?? as i mentioned that i am keeping the Queries External <i.e> In a property file